# How to get the key and value in an array and push it in the table

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to put my JSON array into the table.

“This is for a new Linux server.”

My Json data looks like :

```
{"donutDatas" : [
    {
        "assetClass": "Cash and Short Term Fixed Income",
        "currentValue": "100,527.61",
        "currentPercent": "5.40%"
    },
    {
        "assetClass": "Fixed Income",
        "currentValue": "385,773.45",
        "currentPercent": "20.72%"
    },
    {
        "assetClass": "International Equity",
        "currentValue": "236,582.42",
        "currentPercent": "12.71%"
    },
    {
        "assetClass": "US Equity",
        "currentValue": "997,646.18",
        "currentPercent": "53.58%"
    },
    {
        "assetClass": "Alternative Investments",
        "currentValue": "141,399.59",
        "currentPercent": "7.59%"
    }
  ]
}
```

I called my typescript looks like:

```
onSelectFile(event) {
let tableData = [];
this.displayTable = false;
if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = (e) => {
    tableData = JSON.parse(reader.result.toString());
    this.jsonData = tableData['donutDatas'];
    console.log(this.jsonData);

    const tVal = [];
    this.jsonData.forEach((element) => {
      this.test = Object.values(element);
      console.log(this.test);
      // tVal.push(this.test);
    });
    this.tableVal = this.test;
    console.log(this.tableVal);

    this.displayTable = true;
    const jsonHead = Object.keys(this.jsonData[0]);
    const hval = [];
    jsonHead.map((key, index) => {
      hval.push(key);
    });
    this.tableHead = hval;
  };
  reader.readAsText(event.target.files[0]);
}
// }
}
```

I expect the output the JSON value matches the key in table head and the value bind in the table body.

Comment: `data.donutDatas.map(res => {
... console.log(Object.keys(res));
... console.log(Object.values(res));
... })
`

Comment: edit your question to include the expected result - that'll help you get more answers fast

Comment: Hi Akber,
assetClass, currentValue, currentPercent as a table header and corresponding datas shows under table header.

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Comment: Hi Chellappan, 
Here's my stack blitz URL  "https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mtuijg"

Comment: I found a solution, but the value print in row-wise. I need column-wise. Here is my URL: "https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mtuijg"